# VPN necessity for hosting a hidden service & maintaining anonymity?

Tags: anonymity, bridge, vpn, vps

What are the pros/cons/necessity/redundancy for utilizing a VPN on top of TOR if hosting a hidden service?

I'm aware of the obvious concerns regarding logging if using a commercial VPN service, but if you utilized a service that *doesn't* log IPs (or other data) would it be beneficial or is it redundant with regards to anonymity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make it short and easy:

1. a VPN does **nothing** conducive to anonymity (it is neither *beneficial nor redundant regarding to anonymity*): https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#IsTorLikeAVPN
   Easily explained for casual users: It just makes it seem you are entering "the network" from a different place/country... and depending on your setup (`VPN -> Tor` vs. `Tor -> VPN`) this is in the best case useless or in the worst case can actually harm your anonymity!
2. a VPN somehow just replaces your ISP regarding trust... if you distrust your ISP, why should you trust your VPN provider? (E.g. logging)
3. By [**using bridges**](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html#UsingBridges) instead, you don't need to trust anyone (except the Tor code, which you obviously do).

Note: All of this is also true, no matter if you are hosting a hidden service, providing a relay, just surfing or entering any other network.

Additional an interesting and deeper article about combining Tor:
https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tunnels/Introduction

Comment: """... a VPN just replaces your ISP regarding trust. if you distrust your ISP, why should you trust your VPN provider? (E.g. logging)"""

This is an interesting argument. I can imagine situations where you might indeed trust your VPN provider more than your ISP, if for no other reason than the ISP must have a local presence while the VPN provider might be in a presumably "safer" jurisdiction.

Comment: @newbery: this can be the case if you are surfing the clearweb; but as soon as this is about Tor, using a bridge instead is still by far the best solution!

Comment: Sure. No disagreement regarding using a bridge as the better solution. My comment was solely on the weakness of your argument #2, which suggests there is no advantage to trusting a VPN over an ISP regarding logging in the general case. The argument would be stronger if it's qualified to just when using Tor.