# Combining Mullvad VPN, Kali Linux, and Whonix Gateway; what is the level on anonymity?

Tags: configuration, anonymity, vpn

I have a windows PC connected to Mullvad VPN and a Kali Linux VM connected to Whonix Gateway.
If I start tor on the Kali to set up an .onion website..should I add another layer by connecting to a VPN on Kali as well, or is that set up anon enough?
Not trying to achieve anything specific; just wondering about the level of anonymity. Thanks.

Comment: this probably also answers your question: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/20033/5234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VPN will add little to nothing and possible even harm your anonymity. There is an entire [wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorPlusVPN) written on this.

You will hear this over and over from the [Tor team](https://support.torproject.org/faq/#faq-5):

> Generally speaking, we don't recommend using a VPN with Tor unless
>   you're an advanced user who knows how to configure both in a way that
>   doesn't compromise your privacy.

Comment: Is there a similar page for coupling tor onion service with TLS? I know that there's a reddit post with comments saying "yes, TLS adds nothing and might also harm anonymity of you and or users of onion service", but I'd prefer to read it out from people who designed and built tor.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Kali. Kali is not secure at all. It's made to break security, not be secure itself. For starters, it runs in single-user mode by default.

Comment: what? Could you provide a link with detailed information on this?

Comment: @MuhammadIsmail https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux