# Is Tor completely anonymous?

Tags: anonymity, security, vpn, ip-address, encryption

I saw that tor has three layers of encryptions and, plus a VPN I set myself on my computer. How can someone trace back to my real IP? Is this completely anonymous?

Comment: `encryption != anonymity` - for sure you need encryption for anonymity, but also 100 layers of encryption do **not** ensure that you are anonymous... so a VPN does not really add something for your anonymity, on the contrary it can even harm it! - a little bit more about this topic: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/20033/5234

Comment: @DJCrashdummy well you mean there is no “completely anonymous” or you mean “the vpn may compromise your anonymity” or both?

Comment: i'm saying it seems to me that you are erroneously mixing encryption and anonymity! - and no, i didn't talk about *there is no “complete anonymity"*, because this is more a philosophic topic. but yes, **an additional VPN can compromise your anonymity**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This setup may, or may not, be completely anonymous, depending on a whole bunch of factors, some extremely subtle.  Adding a VPN to Tor basically never improves anonymity, though.  Exactly how someone would trace you back to your real IP is in many cases more about how you use Tor, than Tor itself.

Comment: The correct and honest answer is no. There is no "maybe". But it's as anonymous as anonymous can get. And while this answer is not most direct, I didn't downvote because you didn't say "yes".

Comment: @Sahsahae -- if the cryptography Tor provided is not possible to be wracked with nowadays computation speed, then there's no problem to say "yes". The future is another topic and too far.

Comment: @AkutaHinako If cryptography was the only thing that mattered we might aswell use normal browser, HTTPS cannot be wracked through easily either, just fyi.